# Element not visible in Chrome and IE - Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to perform automation testing using Selenium with Java in Eclipse IDE.

I am finding xpath using the 'Inspect Element' option in chrome browser. However the same xpath is working fine in Firefox browser but NOT in chrome and IE. Can someone help me to solve this in chrome and IE? It throws me 'Element not visible' error in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Probably the problem is related to the XPath itself. Can you please post it?

Comment: Ex: This is how i used it.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lenderName\"]")).click();

Comment: try driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lenderName']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath and Add a wait before it e.g.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='lenderName']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lenderName']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following options to find element :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lenderName")).click();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".lenderName")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lenderName']")).click();
```

If still not work then use Explicit wait with JavascriptExecutor :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("lenderName")));
((JavascriptExecutor)BrowserUtilities.driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",  element);
```

Comment: Sure but don't forget to accept the answer if it worked.